# Puppeteer returning undefined on query

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using `Puppeteer` to check for dead links on a site. These links will have a `h1` with "Page not found" as the content. My understanding is that `page.evaluate` gives access to the `DOM`, but when I try to use it here I get `undefined`. I've tried a few different ways of accessing this data (`.$`, `.$eval`) but so far nothing has worked.

When I enter `document.querySelector('h1', el => el.textContent)` in my dev tools it works correctly. I'm also setting the userAgent, so I'm fairly sure the site doesn't think I'm a bot.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); 

const prepareForTests = async(page) => {
    const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)' +
    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.39 Safari/537.36';
  await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);
}

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await prepareForTests(page);

    const link = await page.goto("https://www.example.com");

    console.log(await page.evaluate(() => {
        document.querySelector('h1', el => el.textContent);
    }));

    await browser.close();
    process.exit();
})();
```

Comment: The page could be dynamic....a network idle in your page.goto would do the trick.....await page.goto('https://example.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

Comment: Along with the answer below, this solved my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this fragment is the issue:

```js
console.log(await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector('h1', el => el.textContent);
}));
```

1. The function does not return the value.
2. `document.querySelector()` accepts only 1 argument, so the second function is ignored.

Try this:

```js
console.log(await page.evaluate(() => {
  return document.querySelector('h1').textContent;
}));
```